# How to create an input field for mm/yyyy?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.6v got struck in one case. I am having a input field where I need to enter a month/year and the range starting from 07/2018 to 12/2019. User should enter any month and year in between that range. I tried html type='month'.
But in IE it is not working. Can any one of you suggest what should i do to validate and allow user only to enter with in that range.

```
 <input type="month" min="07/2018" max="12/2019"
        ng-model="course.plannedMonthYear" value="2018-07"
        error-label="Planned Month/Year" />
```

Comment: Write a [custom validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

Answer (score 0):

The `min` and `max` attributes need to be valid ISO-8601 month format (yyyy-MM):

```
 ̶<̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶=̶"̶m̶o̶n̶t̶h̶"̶ ̶m̶i̶n̶=̶"̶0̶7̶/̶2̶0̶1̶8̶"̶ ̶m̶a̶x̶=̶"̶1̶2̶/̶2̶0̶1̶9̶"̶
 <input type="month" min="2018-07" max="2019-12"
        ng-model="course.plannedMonthYear" value="2018-07"
        error-label="Planned Month/Year" />
```

### [The DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7vZ8IPDW3jvgA6YmBtg0?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.date1=new Date('2018-05');
})
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form name="form1">
       <input type="month" min="2018-06" max="2019-11"
              ng-model="date1"
              name="date1"/>
    </form>
    {{date1 | date : 'MMMM yyyy' }}
    <div class="error" ng-show="form1.date1.$error.min">
      ERROR Date below MIN
    </div>
    <div class="error" ng-show="form1.date1.$error.max">
      ERROR Date above MAX
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but it is not working for IE-11 so please help me in that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the HTML pattern attribute on the input field.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_pattern.asp

> The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the 
>   element's value is checked against.

This will allow you to restrict the date input format as well as min/max values entered.